# starting with python scripts

Tags: python, html

i need to write a python script , the script should access a webpage , which has a "upload" button , normally when you upload a photo with that button a new page opens . and once that page opens i need to look for a string there
so the script should upload there a photo , which i provide to the script and then check the output page for a string

i have no background in that sort of coding (i know basic python ) .

can i get a reference or some pointers on what reading should i do to perform that task? thank you very much

Comment: For your problem look at the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) library. It won't make much sense though if you can't program in python yet. StackOverflow is really for questions you have once you are already coding and have just become stuck as the resources are already available online if you use a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is not specific enough to give you a good answer, I can make a couple of suggestions. I would look into using a library for sending requests to pages, such as [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). I would also look into libraries for parsing html, such as [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Essentially you will need to use requests to get the page's html, and then you'll need to parse that html using Beautiful Soup to find what you're looking for on the page.

You should do some reading about these libraries and/or other similar ones and try to get a better understanding of your problem. Afterward, come back to Stack Overflow once you have more specific questions or problems you've run into.